# How to build Scala report projects

Tags: scala

Is there a common standard to follow for building a SCALA based report engine from scratch. Data will be sourced from HDFS, Filtered, formatted and emailed. Please share any experience or hurdles to expect.

Comment: I think your question is too broad and could be downvoted (or closed). I answered you anyway but next time give more clues, and info about what you planned (here it seems you didn't even try to find a solution by your own)

Answer (score 0):

I used to do such reports as PDF, HTML and XSLX.

We used ElasticSearch but here was the general workflow:

- get filtered data from storage to scala (no real trouble, just make sure your filters are well tested)
- fill the holes to have a consistent data: think about missing points, crazy timezones...
- format (we used an xslt processor to produce email HTML, it is really specific and size for emails is limited, aim ~15 Mo as a very maximum)
- if file is too big, store it somewhere and send the link instead